# How to download the content/image/data of input type file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I wanna know how to download the data/content/image in an input type file

Note: It doesnt have to be submitted. just a direct download from a button in which he can be able to download the content of an input type file

How can i do this?

sample code

```
$(".downloadupinvoice").click(function(){
   var file = document.getElementById('id-input-file-2').files[0];

   //Put some code here to produce a file ?
   window.location=window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
})
```

i cant seem to preview the file but it is not downloading also i notice in the address bar that it display like this

blob:69c7ee1a-ba44-4234-9216-68b3c86b9c96

Comment: those words don't work together that way. An `<input type="file">` lets a user make data available to on-page JavaScript, provided you wrote actual JavaScript to do that. That runs client-side: why would they want to download a file that they already have, because they just selected it with the file input element?

Comment: yeah thats what i thought of also. why would they download a file that they already have. But i just dont know its some sort of a task in which you are able to download the content of an <input type="file" />

anyways is it possible?

Comment: of course. You can get the data from the file input element using javascript, and then you can force-open it as a new window with the correct mimetype (like octet stream) so it triggers as download instead of as a page-thing-to-open-in-the-browser. Easier if you use file-drap-and-drop, though, instead of an `<input type="file">`. Just [drag the file into a dropzone, and off you go](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-dnd-files).

Comment: oh i see thanks :D. It is now clarified, the instruction is a bit misleading thanks for the respond sir ! :D it should have been on the edit page/portion in which you retrieve the file from the server not within the input type file 

anyways if this is possible can you post us some codes sir i think it would be cool to see how to be able to do this :)

Comment: readup on the _download_ attribute of the <a> tag. you can call click() on the <A> tag to init the download...

Answer (score 13):

Finally got it.

```
$(".downloadupaddinvoice").click(function(){
        var filename = $('#id-input-file-2').val();

        if (filename == "" || filename == null) {
            alert('Error');
        }else {
            var file = document.getElementById('id-input-file-2').files[0];      
            var filename = document.getElementById('id-input-file-2').files[0].name;      
            var blob = new Blob([file]);
            var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            $(this).attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': url});  
            filename = "";
        }

    })
```

This is the where the anchor tag :)

```
<a class="help-button col-sm-4 downloadupaddinvoice"  title="Download uploaded invoice" download><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a>
```

Hope it might help in the future..

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution you found. This is exactly what I needed and works perfectly