# Download file which i have selected in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `input type[file]` component.After the user browses and selects a file i need to download the selected file by clicking a button.

```
function download(){
...
}

<input type='file' id='file1'>
<button type='button' onclick='download()'></button>
```

Thanks,
Nawaz Ahmed

Comment: Do you want to upload or download?

Comment: Imagine you are the user, you select the file in browser. So it must already be on your computer to select it. So you might mean upload (to the server) instead of download?

Comment: download @Alexander

Comment: @NawazAhmed why do you need download option ?

Comment: It's Like review page @caramba.So in the final step i need to do that so

Comment: useless actions ?!!

Comment: @NawazAhmed That means you have already uploaded that file ? if yes then you can simply give anchor tag with link to that file and add 'download' attribute to anchor tag

Comment: in the first tab i will select a file..so if the user wants to know the selected file in 12th tab ..it needs to be downloaded @Rakesh Soni

Comment: Either way. If you want to download something it must be on the server first. If it is on the server you do not need an `<input type="file">` cause this is needed to upload files to the server. To download, you just need a link with the path to the file.

Comment: for review purpose you should show preview of file to user instead of giving option to download file and then review

Comment: The file, that user select using by `<input type="file"...>` control, already exist on client machine.. The control allows to **upload** files from client to server. See details on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395727 that might help you

Comment: its an requirement of user :( ... @Rakesh Soni

Comment: @caramba one could argue that once in an `<input>` the user did *upload*  the file to the browser's memory. You can create Files from scratch in a webpage, the action to save it is often called *"download"* (while it may be an Malapropism)

Comment: @Kaiido good point (of view), didn't think about that!

Comment: To OP, there are already  a lot of posts explaining you how to do it. e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547475/save-to-local-file-from-blob The File object you've got in your input is a Blob, so same options will work. Also you might be interested in a library like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) for cross-browser issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save to Local File from Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547475/save-to-local-file-from-blob)

Comment: Check [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page/43523297#43523297) on how to [download a file with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page) it will surely give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
      txt.value = window.onload + '';
      document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(code) {
        this.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,'
          + encodeURIComponent(txt.value);
      };
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txtWrap">
      <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
    </div>

    <a href="" id="link" download="code.txt">Download Above Code</a>
```

may be you can find some idea from here , i am not sure that i am right or wrong according to your question.

Comment: Well... You're not completely wrong either... `<a download>`, when available is the correct way. But why use a dataURI when OP asks for File ? Why wait for a click on the anchor to populate its href ?